# select2 get dropdown options array list

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I am using "select2-selecting" event and would like to get an array with id and labels) of the dropdown.

my code is:

```
$('.mySelect').select2({ ... some options}).on("select2-selecting", function(e) {
    // I need to get an array with dropdown values

});
```

I can get selected values by using $(this).select2('data') and I can get dropdown selector by $(this).select2('dropdown'); but how to get a an array of dropdown list with ids?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `'select2-loaded'` event. It fires before `'select2-selecting'` and you can get actual dropdown list. [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/dizel3d/470yz7un/)

```
$('.mySelect').on('select2-loaded', function(e) {
    dropDownList = e.items.results;
}).on('select2-selecting', function(e) {
    console.log(dropDownList);
});
```